# How to disable context menu while pressing over a image in mobile phone?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you try in chrome pressing and holding an image, a popup comes with option for save it etc. What I am trying to achieve is using an image with touch event to make it move on screen. But whenever I press and hold it I face the above. Any way to remove it?

Comment: I just realised this is unclear - are you specifically trying to prevent downloading, or just *enable* dragging ?

Comment: Prevent downloading, so that user can press and hold and would be able to move it without any popup that usually comes.

Comment: that's what I meant by unclear.   Your _actual intent_ is to _enable_ moving.   You don't actually want to prevent downloading (e.g. to make it harder to steal your image) - you want to _disable the context menu_

Comment: Yes. Sorry didn't clear that earlier. You are right.

Comment: I suggest that you should re-write the title of your question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press and hold on a mobile is the equivalent of a desktop contextmenu event. If you add a handler for this event to your object, return false and call event.preventDefault(); you should not have the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using pointer-events: none; css to the image and target this css only for mobiles using media query.

[More about Pointer events here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to use pointer-events: none, this approach will likely block the logic you intend to apply to your image. What I recommend is to explicitly block the context menu. In React, you can achieve this as follows:

```
<img
    src={imgSrc}
    width={width}
    height={height}
    onContextMenu={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
/>
```